# Converting SOAP to REST?

Tags: rest, soap

I have a web app, that also has an iPhone and Android app using the same API. It hasn't yet been made publicly available, so I wanted to look to convert from SOAP to REST.

I was only able to find a few tutorials that go into thorough explanations of how to code a REST web service, and of those I only found the [MSDN one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx) useful. The problem is I got really confused when they started using URI data types inside the object.

My question is, if you are converting SOAP to REST, do you have to recreate all the objects to add the URI? Am I not able to just have a REST entry point, then call one of the classes that retrieve the data?

Once the REST service is made it will only be used by my mobile apps, but not the website (since that can directly access the classes), which makes me not want to change the objects to add a URI. Is that a correct assumption to make, or should the web services also be called by the website?

Sorry if these are newbie questions, but I am struggling to get my head around REST, and I haven't had much experience creating the architecture of potentially high user base apps.

If anyone is able to point me to an actual code set, that would be helpful.

Edit: I am using VS2010, coding in C# and .Net 4.

Thanks a lot,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im doing a very similar thing right now :). Rest via wcf isnt too hard, you do have to sometimes add your endpoints in the web config and give it the [webget]/[webinvoce] attributes in the refrence.cs of the web refrence when consuming though c# which is annoying.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/RestServiceAPI.aspx) is a code set i used when getting started. There are a few more on code project too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll check out the code. I have kept looking since and as standard, even though I had looked for a week before posting, I found [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/06/introducing-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4.aspx) that seems really, really helpful in explaining.